# HttpContext does not contain a definition for SignOutAsync

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to write a custom authentication manager that will handle user login and logout and many other stuff in my ASP .Net Core 2.x app, but i'm stuck in the first place.

i have tried the way suggested in [this Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) but when i try to implement Sign-in, it shows the `HttpContext does not contain a definition for SignOutAsync` error. i have all the references as suggested in the article :

```
public async void SignIn(HttpContext httpContext, UserDbModel user, bool isPersistent = false)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(this.GetUserClaims(user), CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
        }
```

below code works but it is obsolete :

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(...)
```

references in class :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
```

What's missing here ? maybe these extension-methods are removed in new versions, if so ... how do i implement the authentication in it's correct way ?

Comment: Are you referencing the library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions` in your project references? (see also [AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0))

Comment: after seeing your comment i installed the nuget package addressing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions`, but error is not resolved.

Comment: @igor do i need to reference it in the class file? `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions`, because it causes errors ...

Comment: It is an extension in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication`. You should also be able to access the method using call `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)`

Comment: That said I assume that `HttpContext` is a field in your Controller and that you are not referring to a/the type `HttpContext`. If that is not the case then that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanx! found the problem.

Comment: Looks like I was right about the instance/type, just a mis-type in casing. I added it as answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HttpContext` should be a reference to a field in your `Controller` and that you are not referring to a/the type `HttpContext`. If that is not the case then that is the cause of your problem, change your code to use the field/variable and not the type.

So if the field name is `httpContext` then use that as calling an extension methods is done by referring to the method on an instance and not a type as the instance is also passed in as the first parameter of the extension method.

```
await httpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

Answer (score 4):

insted of

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

should use

```
await httpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,ClaimsPrincipal.Current);
```

or could use

```
await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,ClaimsPrincipal.Current);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, "Cookies");

    AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions
.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

try this in a controller